# Group by inside otherwise clause, spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-14, spark-java

I have this process in SparkJava (IntelliJ app) where I have a problem that I don`t know how to resolve yet.  First I declare the dataset:

```
private static final String CONTRA1 = "contra1";

query = "select contra1, ..., eadfinal, , ..., data_date" + FROM + dbSchema + TBLNAME " + WHERE fech = '" + fechjmCto2 + "' AND s1emp=49";
        Dataset<Row> jmCto2 = sql.sql(query);
```

Then I have the calculations, I analyze some fields to assign some literal values. My problem is in the aggegate function:

```
Dataset<Row> contrCapOk1 = contrCapOk.join(jmCto2,
        contrCapOk.col(CONTRA1).equalTo(jmCto2.col(CONTRA1)),LEFT)
        .select(contrCapOk.col("*"),
        jmCto2.col("ind"),
 
functions.when(jmCto2.col(CONTRA1).isNull(),functions.lit(NUEVES))
     .when(jmCto2.col("ind").equalTo("N"),functions.lit(UNOS))
     .otherwise(jmCto2.groupBy(CONTRA1).agg(functions.sum(jmCto2.col("eadfinal")))).as("EAD"),
```

What I want is to make the sum in the otherwise part.  But when I execute the cluster give me this message in the log.

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset [contra1: int, sum(eadfinal): decimal(33,6)]
```

in the line 211, the otherwise line.

Do you know what the problem could be?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `groupBy` and aggregation function in a column clause. To do what you want to do, you have to use a [window](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html).

For you case, you can define the following window:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec;

...

WindowSpec window = Window
  .partitionBy(CONTRA1)
  .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding(), Window.unboundedFollowing());
```

Where

- `partitionBy` is the equivalent of `groupBy` for aggregation
- `rangeBetween` determine which rows of the partition will be used by aggregation function, here we take all rows

And then you use this window when calling your aggregation function, as follow:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;

...

Dataset<Row> contrCapOk1 = contrCapOk.join(
    jmCto2,
    contrCapOk.col(CONTRA1).equalTo(jmCto2.col(CONTRA1)),
    LEFT
  )
  .select(
    contrCapOk.col("*"),
    jmCto2.col("ind"),
    functions.when(jmCto2.col(CONTRA1).isNull(), functions.lit(NUEVES))
     .when(jmCto2.col("ind").equalTo("N"), functions.lit(UNOS))
     .otherwise(functions.sum(jmCto2.col("eadfinal")).over(window))
     .as("EAD")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Vicent, but its not working fine. I forgot to mention that upper in the code, in the datastset,  I have these lines   " jmCto2 = jmCto2.withColumn("rank", functions.rank().over(rank0));
        jmCto2 = jmCto2.selectht("*").where(jmCto2.col("rank").equalTo(1)); ".  I am not sure but I think that this is avoiding to make the sum.  I think I will have to make a new dataset with the same filters but without the rank clause.  Its that right?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working fine" ? Does your application throw an error ? Does it runs smoothly but you don't get your expected result ? About your `rank` usage, I don't see any problem. How do you define variable `rank0` ?

Comment: Hello again, There is no error message.  The code throws a result of one file, there is no sum.  This is that part of the code:          WindowSpec rank0 = Window.partitionBy(CONTRA1,FEOPERAC).orderBy(jmCto2.col(DATA_DATE_PART).desc());
        jmCto2 = jmCto2.withColumn("rank", functions.rank().over(rank0));
        jmCto2 = jmCto2.select("*").where(jmCto2.col("rank").equalTo(1));
        jmCto2 = jmCto2.drop("rank");

Comment: I don't think your problem comes from `rank` part of your code, it seems totally legit. However, I still don't understand what you're exactly expecting as a result of your select. Can you add some sample of input dataframe (dataframe on which you apply select) and what do you expect as output dataframe in your question ? It will help me to get what you want to do.

Comment: I will try to explain:  jmCto2 dataset:  query = "select contra1,fincalcu,motexinf,flgtittr,ind_ingr,criavesc,k2,eadfinal,lgdfinal,in_pdini," +
"data_date_part,feoperac" + FROM + dbSchemaDlgeSsiiCapBdrirbH + JM_CTO_CATEG2 +  " WHERE feoperac = '" + fecJmCto2 + "' AND s1emp=49";  Dataset<Row> jmCto2 = sql.sql(query);    In JM_CTO_CATEG2  table I have for example, two files with same CONTRA1, so I want the sum of eadfinal in the final table.

Comment: There are filters for the fields  fincalcu=1 ,motex=0, flgtittr=0  that are in the dataset  jmCto2 = jmCto2.withColumn("ind",functions
.when(jmCto2.col(FINCALCU).equalTo(1).and(jmCto2.col(MOTEXINF).equalTo(0)).and(jmCto2.col(FLGTITTR).equalTo("0"))
                        .and(jmCto2.col(IND_INGR).equalTo("0")),functions.lit("S"))
                .otherwise(functions.lit("N")));   I woul like to show you more code, but the space is limite here.

Comment: I just realized in a another part of the code say this for the same jmCto2:           WindowSpec rank = Window.partitionBy(CONTRA1).orderBy(jmCto2.col("ind").desc());
        jmCto2 = jmCto2.withColumn("rank", functions.rank().over(rank));
        jmCto2 = jmCto2.select("*").where(jmCto2.col("rank").equalTo(1));
        jmCto2 = jmCto2.dropDuplicates(CONTRA1);    If I am dropping duplicates there will be only one register.  Coul be that the problem?.  I will test.

Comment: Hello again,  I have been checking my code I have made some adjustments.  I applied you portion of the code and the result was fantastic, this was what I wanted.  Thank you again and excuse me if my explanations were not very accurate.-  Thanks.